# Trying to upgrade Typescript using npm in Linux Mint

Tags: typescript, npm

I have typescript 2.1.4, npm 6.7.0.

I think that 2.1.4 is quite old and I am trying to update.

These are my failed attempts:

```
$ sudo npm update -g typescript
$ tsc --version
Vesion 2.1.4

$ sudo npm install -g typescript@latest
/usr/local/bin/tsc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
/usr/local/bin/tsserver -> 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
+ typescript@3.3.1
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 1.229s
$ tsc --version
Version 2.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `which tsc`. It should point to `/usr/local/bin/tsc` as that is what is getting installed according to your log.

## Example

Here is an example log that shows a successful upgrade:

```
$ tsc --version 
Version 2.4.2

$ npm install -g typescript@latest
/usr/local/bin/tsserver -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsserver
/usr/local/bin/tsc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
+ typescript@3.3.1
updated 1 package in 2.121s

$ which tsc 
/usr/local/bin/tsc

$ tsc --version 
Version 3.3.1
```

Comment: Yes I have done exactly as you, the messages showing after the install are the same, but when I do the final version, I still get 2.1.4 :(

Comment: `npm uninstall typescript -g` And then `which tsc`. There should be none 

Comment: Strange. It was `/usr/local/bin/tsc` before, now it is `/usr/bin/tsc` and npm doesn't know about it